# IExtensibleDataObject

Tags: .net

guys.  I'm not asking here a particular question.  The question is: what is your opinion on .NET IExtensibleDataObject interface and the whole mechanism used in terms of stability?  Have you used it?  Is that a reasonable solution if I suspect that my business object shall morph with time?  It seems that it can support new members in new versions of a class, but it seems that IExtensibleDataObject class implementation is NOT stable to the changes to old member types.
May be you have some criticism about this mechanism and I will be glad to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

It does its job, which is to allow you to safely round-trip unexpected data without loss. Allowing old clients to talk to new servers, and new clients to talk to old servers.

Re "changes to old member types"; if you mean you've changed the definition of an existing member, then frankly all bets are off. Most serializers work on a *contract* (implicit or explicit) about the data. If you *change* a member, you have broken the contract.

It is generally better to *replace* a member rather than change it; or better - version the entire DTO (i.e. release a *new* contract, that is independent to the original).

---

Actually, my biggest gripe about this interface is that it deals with a concrete implementation (`ExtensionDataObject`). But that is more related to my *specific* whims, from the perspective of someone who maintains a serialization utility library...

Comment: Well, it seems that this scenario does not work for my problem.  I have settings serialized to disk and have dialog box for modifying these settings bound through binding source.  So, suppose at first I bound it to ObjectVersion1, entered data and serialized it to myfile.dat.  Then I updated databindings to ObjectVersion2 to edit additional fields in this new object.  If I try now to deserialize myfile.dat with its ObjectVersion1 instance, databinding will fail due to the fact, that some member values are not present in ObjectVersion1 (in Members of ExtensionObject field).